# SetExpressCheckout (NVP Legacy API) and Brazil

Tags: paypal

I just updated our application to use the latest version of the legacy NVP API and discovered mention of two new fields (TAXIDTYPE, TAXID) that are apparently required for Brazil. These apparently were introduced after the version of the API we were previously using.

I just tried sending a locale of BR (Brazil) and neglecting to send these new fields and everything worked just fine.

So my questions are:

- are they really required?
- if so, what exactly are they? Can't find any explanation beyond the API docs (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp) and it's unclear what these fields are. Do people/businesses in Brazil have a TAXID that they're meant to submit when making online purchases?

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regulatory requirement for Brazilian merchants to capture buyer's tax id. These fields are not required if are not a Brazilian merchant.